# Git and Eclipse: show files outside of a project

Tags: eclipse, egit

Disclaimer: I'm new to EGit but familiar with command line Git.

In Eclipse Neon, I have a configured Git repository with this structure:

```
.git
README.md
.gitignore
projectA
  .project
projectB
  .project
projectC
  .project
```

Problem: In *Enterprise Explorer*, *Navigator*, *Project*, and *Package Explorer*, I can only see `ProjectA`, `ProjectB`, and `ProjectC`, not `README.md` and `.gitignore`.

Question: How can I modify `README.md` and `.gitignore` from inside Eclipse?

Environment: Under *Enterprise Explorer > Available Customizations*, I have unchecked `.*resources`. Under *Navigator > Filters* I have unchecked `.*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Package/Project Explorer*, *Navigator*, etc. show only files of into Eclipse imported/opened projects. Files that are starting with `.` are hidden in the *Package/Project Explorer*, but are shown in the *Navigator* view by default.

1. In the ***Git Repositories*** view navigate to the file under the ***Working Tree* node** and double-click to open the file. Alternatively, use *File > Open File...*.
2. Edit and save the file
3. In the *Git Stagging* view commit/push the file as usual

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to what [@howlger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6505250/howlger) suggested is to create a project at the root of the repository working directory so that the readme and gitignore file become members of the workspace.

**Create a General Project at the root of the working directory**

Open the *New Project* wizard (*File* > *New* > *Project*) to create a *General Project*. Choose a project name of your choice, uncheck the *Use default location* checkbox, and enter the location of the repositories' working directory in the *Location* input field.

This will create a `.project` file with project metadata in the root of the working directory. If all team members use Eclipse as their IDE, it may make sense to commit this file to the repository.

**(Optionally) use resource filters to exclude nested projects**

Now, the *Package Explorer* and other navigation views show a project that contains all files and folders within the working directory, including folders that contain nested projects.

Resource filters can be used to exclude folders that contain nested projects so that only those files and folders appear that are not already shown within other projects.

To add a resource filter, open the *Properties* dialog of the root-level project and open the *Resource* > *Resource Filters* page. Often, all nested projects follow a common naming pattern. In this case a *File and Folder Attributes* filter that specifys a pattern to match the folder name can be used to exlude them. Otherwise, the [*Extras for Eclipse*](https://rherrmann.github.io/eclipse-extras/) plug-ins offer a feature to exclude all *Nested Wprkspace Projects*.

**Pros and Cons**

Having all files in a repository within the IDE allows to easily edit and navigate through files including decorators that indicate the change status of all files.

Some users, however, may consider having an extra `.project` file at the root directory of the repository as a downside.